# Gradle inspection doesn't works fine

Tags: java, gradle, build, attributes, manifest

I have **IDEA marks all inside attributes colons with warning!**

```
task configureJar (dependsOn : 'generateVersion', type : Jar) {
    archiveName = "${applicationName}_ver${version}.${extension}"
    println archiveName
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Implementation-Title" : applicationName,
                "Implementation-Version" : version,
                "Developer" : developer
        )
    }
}
```

It says that `'attributes' cannot be applied to '([Implementation-Title':java.lang.Object, 'Implementation-Version':java.lang.Object,...])`
But the task builds fine.

I have also some minor mistakes about inspection with Gradle plugin.
What's going on and how to fix?

P.S.: i'd like to notice , that manifest described in `jar {  }` section does not shows a warning.